# How to add test parameters to PHP code

Tags: php, debugging, testing, variables

I am looking to set test parameters into my variables that I have written, however they recieve their data through the POST method, what's the best way to test my code by presetting the variables myself, e.g. thisRate->$fromCurr = 'GBP' rather than always testing through the browser...

Thanks

Comment: Depends on how your code handles the set variables. Care to share some of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_POST['myVar'] = "test";
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: That's how I would do it. Just set them at the top of your script and it will treat it like a form has been "post"ed with those values.

Comment: Yes I think so, i'll just attach the test variables to the get variables

Comment: sorry did mean the GET method not POST but should still work the same hopefully

Comment: Yes, you can set $_GET or $_POST variables directly in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to work through post while testing, you could just set another variable and use that until you know it works. Instead of using `$_POST['myvar']` you could use `$myvar`.